# Docker-Compose: Composing with Dockerfiles that need relative imports

Tags: go, docker, docker-compose

To begin, this is my project hierarchy:

```
myproj/
    - commons1/
        - com1_file1.go
        - ...
    - commons2/
        - com2_file1.go
        - ...
    - module1/
        - mod1_file1.go
        - Dockerfile
        - ...
    - module2/
        - mod2_file1.go
        - Dockerfile
        - ...
    - docker-compose.yml
```

What I'd like to do is that when `module1` and `module2` containers start up, they each have a copy of all the `commonsN` directories in their `GOPATH`'s so that each can access the common libraries exposed by each of the `commonsN` directories.

For example, I would like to see something like this in the container for `module1`:

```
/go/
    - src/
        - commons1/
            - com1_file1.go
            - ...
        - commons2/
            - com2_file1.go
            - ...
        - module1/
            - mod1_file1.go
            - ...
```

Reason being is that this is basically how my local `GOPATH` looks (with the addition of the other modules of course) so that I can do something like this in my source files:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "myproj/commons1"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Some thing from common library :", commons1.SomethingFromCommons)
}
```

From my naive understanding of Docker, it appears I'm not allowed to modify my Dockerfiles to do something along the lines of `COPY ../commons1 /go/src/commons1`, so I'm wondering how I would go about accomplishing this?

I would strongly prefer to not go the Github route since the source code is all behind company proxies and whatnot and I'm imagining configuring all that is going to take way longer than simply copying some directories.

**Edit**
I have updated my `docker-compose.yml` file to look something like this per suggestion from barat:

```
version: '2'

services:
    module1:
        volumes:
            - ./commons1:/go/src/myproj/commons1
        build: module1/
```

Dockerfile for `module1` looks like this:

```
FROM golang:1.8.0

RUN mkdir -p /go/src/app
WORKDIR /go/src/app

COPY . /go/src/app
RUN go get -d -v
RUN go install -v

ENTRYPOINT /go/bin/app

EXPOSE 8080
```

`docker-compose build` fails on the `go get -d -v` with error:

> package myproj/commons1: unrecognized import path "myproj/commons1" (import path does not begin with hostname)

If `myproj/commons1` was copied into `/go/src/`, then this shouldn't be an issue right? I'm guessing then it hasn't been copied over then?

Comment: But in docker-compose you can bind-mount your host volume/directories ... https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes-volumedriver

Comment: Ok yea I read that but I wasn't entirely sure how that worked. Would I just add a line like `./commons1:/go/src/commons1` as a volume under `volumes` in the compose file?

Comment: yes - left part (before :) is Your host path, and right part (after :) defines mount point inside container. You can use multiple of those :)

Comment: Hmm, well now I can't tell if that's exactly working, but this might be more go related. I will update the post to reflect the new issue I'm facing.

Comment: @barat it looks like I didn't do the `volumes` thing correctly in the `docker-compose.yml` because my build seems to be indicating to me that the directory doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

You could build an image including `commons1` and `commons2` that your other images are based on.

```
FROM golang:1.8.0
RUN mkdir -p /go/src/myproj/commons1 && mkdir -p /go/src/myproj/commons2
COPY commons1/ /go/src/myproj/commons1/
COPY commons2/ /go/src/myproj/commons2/
```

The downside is this requires an external build step whenever you update one of the common projects:

```
docker build -t me/myproj:commons .
```

Then your compose apps can rely on the commons image instead of `golang` and build as normal without the volumes.

```
FROM me/myproj:commons
...
```

Answer (score 0):

So problem was the `go get -d -v` command since it was complaining `myproj/commons1` wasn't installed in `$GOPATH/src` basically. This I of course suspect was because Docker Compose wasn't mounting the volumes I mentioned before it ran the `go get` on `docker-compose build` so I made a work around in my `docker-compose.yml` but it is far from elegant:

```
version: '2'

services:
    module1:
        volumes:
            - ./commons1:/go/src/myproj/commons1
        build: module1/
        ports:
            - "8080:8080"
        command: bash -c "go get -d -v && go install -v && /go/bin/app
```

This is obviously far from ideal because my Go binary is rebuilt every time I do a `docker-compose up` regardless of whether or not I ran `docker-compose build`.

This is also problematic because I wanted to use `dockerize` for certain containers to wait until another container has started up completely and it becomes quite messy now I think.